# Writing a query to achieve below results

Tags: sql

```
I have three tables A,B,C.
Table A -> A_id, name
Table B -> B_id, A_id, C_id
Table C -> C_id, a1, a2
```

I have C_id with me and need to fetch all the records from A table which have id = a1 or id = a2 or ids for which C_id matches between table B and C?

```
eg.
A_id  Name
A     Table
1     jon
2     Alice
3     Bob
4     Clara

B Table
B_id A_id C_id
1     1     1
2     4     1
3     2     2
4     4     2

C Table
C_id a1 a2
1     1 3
```

If I want to fetch for C_id = 1 I should get 1, 3, 4

Comment: Please add column name headings to the published sample data

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: @P.Salmon Added the column headers

Comment: There aren't any c_id = 3 in b so is there some additional logic you haven't mentioned that would cause 3 to appear in your desired result , also it would be helpful if you included name in your result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select a.a_id
from b
join a on a.a_id = b.a_id
where b.c_id = 1
union 
select a.a_id
from c
join a on a.id = c.a1 or a.id = c.a2
where c.id = 1
```